# cassandra is not running as service

Tags: cassandra

The system is Linux 14.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64,  200GB space, 8GB memory. Everything is done in both root and user. We installed the Cassandra version 3.6.0 from datastax using the following command (followed the instruction from website: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/install/installDeb.html):

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install datastax-ddc
```

However, the cassandra is not started as service.

```
root@e7:~# nodetool status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.
root@e7:~# service cassandra start
root@e7:~# service cassandra status
 * Cassandra is not running
```

We can start Cassandra manually using the command:

```
$ cassandra -R -f
...

INFO  18:45:02 Starting listening for CQL clients on /127.0.0.1:9042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  18:45:02 Binding thrift service to /127.0.0.1:9160
INFO  18:45:02 Listening for thrift clients...
INFO  18:45:12 Scheduling approximate time-check task with a precision of 10 milliseconds
```

---

```
root@e7:~# nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  153.45 KiB  256          100.0%            28ba16df-1e4c-4a40-a786-ebee140364bf  rack1
```

However, we have to start cassandra as a service. Any suggestions how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installDeb.html
This is more stable and I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ports are not opened.
Try opening the following ports:

Cassandra inter-node ports

```
Port number Description
7000    Cassandra inter-node cluster communication.
7001    Cassandra SSL inter-node cluster communication.
7199    Cassandra JMX monitoring port.
```

Cassandra client port

```
Port number Description
9042    Cassandra client port.
9160    Cassandra client port (Thrift).
```

Also what type of Snitch is defined in the Cassandra.yaml file ?

Comment: The problem is solved by using another version of the cassandra. Previous one is  DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra™ 3.x . Now I am using Apache Cassandra™ 3.0 and the problem is gone. Here is the version I am using now: 
    
[http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installDeb.html](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installDeb.html)